# iPad split view loaded as view not in main window

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I need to load my split view in a xib not connected to the main xib, (it works for me if I create a split view connected to the main xib.)
[uisplit tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1040/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uisplitview-tutorial) (main with the root view controller, and calling the right side of the split)

But from a second view (another xib) not main xib, I dont have the app delegate in my view...or the other components of the split view.)

How can I load the new view with the split view?  Should I put another app delegate in my new xib?

Comment: Can you publish ur code in here